# Windows 10 Task Scheduler error "XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted"

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

Since the Windows 10 upgrade any attempt to edit a previously existing task results in a popup error window stating:

> **An error has occurred for task < taskname >**
>   The following error was reported: The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range..

I found a workaround.  If I go to General->Change User or Group... and just re-enter the current user, the edits are accepted.  Old tasks that were created under Windows 8 and new tasks (after successful creation) behave the same way: any edits must be followed by a user name re-entry.

Comment: I sometimes get this importing a task exported from the same version of Windows Server  (2019) and from older versions. I compared the XML to the previous server version, it was the same. This fix, re-selecting the user account to run as, worked. The error is misleading in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error, chances are you have this
 `([timeSpan]::maxvalue)`
  in one of your commands.

Example:
`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 35) -RepetitionDuration ([timeSpan]::maxvalue)`

A workaround is to set the statemnt with a specfic time somewhere in the distant future.
`$TheDate= ([DateTime]::Now)
$Duration = $TheDate.AddYears(25) -$TheDate

New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 35) -RepetitionDuration $Duration`

Credit to [blog.netnerds](https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/create-scheduled-task-or-scheduled-job-to-indefinitely-run-a-powershell-script-every-5-minutes/#comment-50357)

Comment: You refer to PowerShell commands.  I'm not sure how that ties in to my problem with Windows Task Scheduler but I discovered that the error is no longer occurring.  There have been many Windows 10 updates since I posted so I have to assume this got fixed at some point.

Comment: Thanks! This way fixed my problem, since the PS version is 5.1 on Windows Server 2016, I can't use `([timeSpan]::maxvalue)` which was working on PS 4.0.

Comment: You saved my day ! Could not have guessed it

Comment: more than 25 years (e.g. 50) doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Check this 3 locations for the task with the name in the error message:

- File system:

  - C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
- Registry:

  - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tasks
  - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache\Tree

Any occurrence of the task name from the error message is to be removed.

Make a backup of the keys, just in case ...

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason is that the task's XML contains `MaintenanceSettings` element. Something like:

```
<Task …>
  …
  <Settings>
    …
    <MaintenanceSettings>
      <Period>P1D</Period>
      <Deadline>P7D</Deadline>
      <Exclusive>false</Exclusive>
    </MaintenanceSettings>
…
```

For instance, built-in Microsoft Defender tasks contain these.

Note that Task Scheduler doesn't have UI to edit these settings.
According to [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskschedulerschema-maintenancesettings-maintenancesettingstype-element), `MaintenanceSettings` were added in Windows 8 whereas most other elements exist since Windows Vista. So, we may speculate whether UI was not updated in time, or they intentionally decided not to implement UI for this setting. Another element that was added lately is `WnfStateChangeTrigger`. Task Scheduler lists it in Triggers tab, but says that can't edit it.

You could export the task in XML file, edit it with Notepad and import back.
While editing in Notepad, you could remove `MaintenanceSettings` element from XML. Then re-imported the task will become editable with Task Scheduler UI. Or, you could make all your edits in Notepad and keep `MaintenanceSettings`.

And (according to my tests) re-entering the username doesn't work around this `MaintenanceSettings` issue.